# Entity Framework - Code First - Multiple projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I have one solution with three projects in it:

```
ToDo.Web  
ToDo.Core  
ToDo.Data
```

ToDo.Web is my startup project and is an MVC 4 solution.
ToDo.Core is a Class Library solution and it contains all my classes like User, Task etc.
ToDo.Data is my data repository and contains my ToDoContext model.

My ToDoModel model looks like this:

```
namespace ToDo.Data
{
  public class ToDoModel : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the project to create my database on my locally installed SQL Server 2012. So in my web.config (in the ToDo.Web project) I have the following connectionstring:

```
<add name="ToDo.Data.ToDoModel" connectionString="Data Source=XXX\YYY;Integrated Security=SSPI;initial catalog=ToDo" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I then try to execute the following command from Package Manager Console:
Enable-Migrations -projectname ToDo.Data -StartUpProjectName ToDo.Web

The command executes nicely with no errors. And I can see a Migrations folder in my ToDo.Data project. But it only contains a Configuration.cs file and no information about my model. And I cannot see the database being created on my SQL server either.

I have tried creating a simple Console application, using the same connection string where it works nicely.

I have tried adding the connection string to my app.config in the ToDo.Data project without luck.

Anyone who can guide me in the right direction?

Comment: I have built a solution like yours and I have the same result: a Migrations folder with only a Configuration.cs file. Then I have used my ToDoModel in the web application (loading all the Users and the Index action of my Home controller) and launching the application the database has been created. Are you sure you are using your ToDoModel in the web application?

Comment: Ah... I might have forgot the Update-Database command (or to execute something where I use the db...) At the moment I have not created anything that would actually use the db, but the update-database command in packange manager console should do it. Will try again after work to see what happens and let you know. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: How dumb can one be (me, myself and I) :-). Yes, I did forget to run the update-database command! So the full command I gave was: Update-Database -ProjectName ToDo.Data -StartupProjectName ToDo.Web. Thank you Danielle for pointing me in the right direction!